# Узнать тип объектов, хранящихся в объекте, реализующем интерфейс IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list

Нужно узнать тип объектов, хранящихся в объекте, реализующем интерфейс IEnumerable < T>
Я сделал так (это неправильный вариант):

```
Type itemsType = null;
foreach (var item in source)
{
    itemsType = item.GetType();
    break;
}
```

Думаю должен быть способ получше.

**Update: Объект коллекции реализует IEnumerable< T>, нужно узнать тип T**

Comment: Возможно подойдет один из следующих способов:             
            object.GetType().GetElementType();
            object.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

Comment: а если коллекция пустая?

Comment: https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/blob/master/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/Internals/EnumerableExt.cs#L11 <- как вариант

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Код по вашей ссылке упадёт на таком классе: `class X : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string> { ... }`.

Comment: @VladD, а так можно было??? А хотя да, явная реализация интерфейса

Comment: @VladD можно поподробнее?

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Ну, упадёт вот эта строка: https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/blob/master/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/Internals/TypeExt.cs#L32, т. к. `SingleOrDefault` бросит исключение, если у объекта будет несколько интерфейсов типа `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: @VladD это понятно, интересно практическое применение подобного класса `X`

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Не знаю, если честно, можно придумать. Но пойнт не в этом, а в том, что в коде баг.

Comment: @VladD не уверен, что в данном (касательно библиотеки, а не вопроса автора) случае это может считаться багом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написал так:

```
object list = new List<string>();
var type = list.GetType();

// получаем список интерфейсов, фильтруем обобщённые интерфейсы
// имеющие вид IEnumerable<T>
var ienumerableInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces()
      .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

// для каждого из интерфейсов получаем тип элемента
var itemTypes = ienumerableInterfaces.Select(i => i.GetGenericArguments()[0]);

foreach (var item in itemTypes)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

Comment: Ага, я как то упустил ```IEnumerable``` интерфейс в вопросе, а так то ваш вариант понадежнее будет :)

Comment: почему-то мне кажется, что в вопросе речь шла про `IEnumerable`, а не `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Grundy: Если про `IEnumerable`, то ответ тривиален: `object`.

Comment: @VladD, подозреваю речь шла о том, что туда что-то запхали, явно не object, и сейчас хотят узнать, а что именно :)

Comment: @Grundy: Тип конкретного объекта можно узнать через `GetType`, это тоже тривиально. Если тип ограничен компилятором, это `IEnumerable<T>`, точка. Иначе общий тип элементов коллекции — `object`, проверка одного элемента ничего не даёт. Если это необобщённый `IEnumerable`, то внутри _всегда_ может оказаться `new object()`.

Comment: @tym32167: Спасибо!

Comment: _Тип конкретного объекта можно узнать через GetType_ - именно это и происходит в вопросе сейчас :)

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как из коллекции типов получить общий для всех элементов тип?

Comment: @mirypoko: Коллекция из более чем одного типа будет только в том безумно редком случае, когда класс реально имплементирует _несколько_ интерфейсов. Например, `IEnumerable<int>` и `IEnumerable<string>`. В нормальных случаях в коллекции будет один тип, так что вы можете использовать `itemTypes.First()`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете попробовать проверить свойство [GenericTypeArguments](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.generictypearguments), которое вернет массив аргументов типа.

```
object list = new List<string>();   
var type = list.GetType();

if (type.IsGenericType)
    Console.WriteLine(type.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name);
```

Однако, следует иметь ввиду, что для не обобщенных классов это **не** сработает, например

```
class Foo : List<string> // это не обобщенный класс
{
}
```

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: @VladD, возможно за отсутствие объяснений?

Comment: @Grundy справедливо. Добавил немного текста.